# access denied error after submitting php.mysql form

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Access denied for user '...'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in on line 2






     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xyz","xyz@123"); 
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 Print "no connect"; 
} mysql_select_db("digifivm_prosperria", $con);
     $sql="INSERT INTO digifivm_prosperria.advertise (iam, type, iwant, name, email, phoneno, query) VALUES ('$_POST[iam]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[iwant]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_‌​POST[phoneno]','$_POST[query]')"; mysql_close($con);
```

I have created 2 tables i.e. enquiry & advertise in a database i.e. xyz_db. When I am submitting advertise form I have got this warning error... I have used same database, username & password in another form (enquiry)-this form is working fine..

Comment: The error is quite clear, but without code we can't help

Comment: there has to be something different, inspect the files closely

Comment: <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xyz","xyz@123");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
Print "no connect";
  }
mysql_select_db("digifivm_prosperria", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO digifivm_prosperria.advertise (iam, type, iwant, name, email, phoneno, query)
VALUES
('$_POST[iam]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[iwant]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phoneno]','$_POST[query]')";

mysql_close($con);

Comment: is your db password correct? double check it.

Comment: @user1471909 Please add (edit) that to the post itself.

Comment: @curious_coder yes its correct, Ive used same DB Username and password in another form and the form is working fine....

Comment: Either the username or the password is misspelled.

Comment: Thanks a lot every body....

Answer (score 1):

Check the mysql username, password and database name.